# Making textfield greyed out/disabled after saving data to database (ajax/php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, textfield

I have the following code:

```
<input type="text" value="name" id="name" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" /></p>

<script>
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
        var text = $("#name").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'page.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                text: text
            },
            success: function(response) {
                alert("inserted");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and everything works fine now, but after clicking the button I get the popup msg (alert) saying the data was inserted. Instead of that I want to grey out the textfield - is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `disabled` attribute to the input in your success callback?

Comment: Next time please attempt to google this. "jquery disable input" would have given you the same answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the text input disabled using `prop()`. This will also grey it out in most browsers. Try this:

```
success: function(response) {
    $('#name').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function disable(){
  $("#name").prop("disabled",true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way after `ajax` success callback,

```
    $("#name").attr('readonly', 'true'); // mark it as read only
    $("#name").css('background-color' , '#DEDEDE'); // change the background color
```